# Mongodb query: search regex in nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Given the folowing document structure of recorded games:

```js
{
...
"rightkingpercenthp":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0.94,0.95,0],
"gameDetails":[
 {"playername":"Calvino",
 ...
 "unitsPerWave":[
  ["grarl_unit_id:0.5|9.5"],
  ["hydra_unit_id:3.5|6.5","veteran_unit_id:1.5|6","grarl_unit_id:3.5|5.5","peewee_unit_id:8.5|7"],        ["hydra_unit_id:3.5|6.5","veteran_unit_id:1.5|6","veteran_unit_id:8.5|7","peewee_unit_id:8.5|6",
    "fatalizer_unit_id:2.5|5"],
    ...
    ]
}
```

How can i count the amount of games with at least one e.g. "veteran_unit_id" in gameDetails.unitsPerWave (ignoring coordinates after the name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) operators to query within your nested `gamesDetails.unitsPerWave` array and a regex that matches the beginning of the strings:

```
db.col.count({
    'gameDetails.unitsPerWave': {$elemMatch: {$elemMatch: {$regex: /^veteran_unit_id/}}}
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I would upvote your answer but i cant, since i dont have enough points :(

Comment: It looks like this "query" will work with On2 speed.

Comment: @JohnnyHK oh sry done. And how would i count the amount of gameDeatils with veteran_unit_id in it (like this it counts the amount of games where any of its gamedetails.unitsperwave has a veteran in it)? I want to provide pick/winchances so i would need to add gameDeatils.gameresult:won/lost, but since every game has a winner and loser i just get all games returned :S

Answer (score -3):

In this case, IMHO, any super-duper mongoDB query will be equal to just a simple pass through every record in the database.